# Debian testing - upgrade "Buster" to "Bullseye" version, no server for security.debian.org

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, software-updates, dist-upgrade

I tried to upgrade my Debian System using `apt`, the repository is set to "testing" so I expected it to change to the next version "Bullseye" from "Buster" automatically but since "Buster" moved on I get:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.12.204 80]
```

when running `apt update`.

The `security.debian.org` address does not seem to have Release files, did the address change?

```
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org testing/updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

this are the relevant entries of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

I checked `man apt-secure` but could not find or understand the relevant information.

---

**Update:** I got two answers so far, both referring to the ofical [debian.org](https://debian.org) page, but suggest a complete different solution. Can someone please explain, since I decided to not remove the `security.debian.org` entries, but changed the version-attribute format.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From https://wiki.debian.org/Status/Testing

```
deb http://security.debian.org testing-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org testing-security main contrib non-free
```

The entries slightly changed after the latest release.

Here is [an announcement to debian-devel-announce](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/07/msg00004.html):

> ... over the last years we had people getting confused over -updates (recommended updates) and /updates (security updates). Starting with Debian 11 "bullseye" we have therefore renamed the suite including the security updates to -security. An entry in sources.list should look like
>
> ```
> deb security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
> ```
>
> For previous releases the name will not change.

Answer (score 3):

Its a little bit confusing, but

> If you are tracking testing or the next-stable code name, you should always have a corresponding deb http://security.debian.org <"testing" or codename>-security main line in your /etc/apt/sources.list . See this FAQ-Item. https://www.debian.org/security/faq#testing:
>
> Q: How is security handled for testing?
>
> A: Security for testing benefits from the security efforts of the entire project for unstable. However, there is a minimum two-day migration delay, and sometimes security fixes can be held up by transitions. The Security Team helps to move along those transitions holding back important security uploads, but this is not always possible and delays may occur. Especially in the months after a new stable release, when many new versions are uploaded to unstable, security fixes for testing may lag behind. If you want to have a secure (and stable) server you are strongly encouraged to stay with stable.

I think you should NOT disable the security updates for testing and keep a line like

> deb http://security.debian.org testing-security main

Comment: thanks for the clarification! Especially for the bit about the `security-updates`. Did not feel right to disable the upgrades anyway!

Comment: Here's the source for the quoted text in case anyone is looking for it: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting (the same link in GAD3R's answer)

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade to testing you should disable the security updates.

[How to upgrade to Debian (next-stable) Testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting)

> To upgrade to testing from current stable, if you have already installed the stable release:
>
> 2.Remove or comment out your stable security updates line(s) (anything with security.debian.org in it).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem going from buster to testing, and tried the suggestions here. Still did not work. I went to [the link provided](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/07/msg00004.html) by [rlandster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14097/rlandster) in a comment in the accepted answer. Following that, I changed the entry to:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ testing-security main
```

and then `sudo apt update` worked properly.